# jQuery .closest() works on one page, but not another

Tags: jquery

http://www.gamingunion.net/
http://www.gamingunion.net/forums/

When you click on the game background it'll open a Amazon.com link. For some reason on the forums it's failing and giving the error **$(event.target).closest is not a function**.

http://www.bungieunion.com/gamingunion/js/forum.js

The second function is the one in question. The jQuery version is the same on both pages, so I can't figure out what the issue could possibly be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the target is an HTML DOM object, not a jquery object. I would test to see if the event.target is an instanceof jQuery like so:

```
var target = (event.target instanceof jQuery) ? event.target : jQuery(event.target);
```

This will ensure that the target object is a jQuery object before calling .closest()

Edit: changed $ to jQuery in case of using noConflict

Edit #2: I changed your entire second method to this:

```
var _body = jQuery("body");

_body.click(function() {
    // affilate takeover functions
    if( _body.attr('id').length 
        && _body.closest('header').length == 0 
        && _body.closest('#wrapper > nav').length == 0 
        && _body.closest('#leaderboard > div').length == 0 
        && _body.closest('#wrapper2').length == 0 
        && _body.closest('body > footer').length == 0 
        && _body.attr('name') != 'userfile' 
        && _body.closest('.ui-datepicker-calendar').length == 0 
        && _body.closest('.ui-datepicker-prev').length == 0 
        && _body.closest('.ui-datepicker-next').length == 0 
        && _body.closest('.editor_control_bar').length == 0 
        && _body.closest('.ui-autocomplete').length == 0 
        && _body.closest('#fancybox-overlay').length == 0 
        && _body.closest('#fancybox-wrap').length == 0 
        && _body.attr('href') != '#shoutbox' 
        && !_body.hasClass('ui-button-text') 
        && _body.closest('.ui-dialog').length == 0) {
        // variables
        var affiliate_url = jQuery("input[name=affiliate_url]").val();

        window.open(affiliate_url);
    }
});
```

Comment: Any idea why it would fail on the forums but not the main website?

Comment: Ugh, I think I found the issue, apparently one of the other .js files is interfering w/ it.

Comment: @Shawn, cool no worries. Sorry for taking so long. I was having a hard time debugging it because I couldn't find the same js file on the actual website to set breakpoints, so I was actually just using the console in Chrome to clear the existing click event and substitute the one I wrote above. Anyways, good luck with the site, looks nice so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think the amazon affiliate script is loading jQuery version 1.2.6 after your scripts are loaded, and after you call `jQuery.noConflict()`. If you look at `$` and `jQuery` in the watch panel in IE9, you'll see they are not the same. The script loaded is

`http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/browser-scripts/us-site-wide-1.2.6/site-wide-10148190434.js._V178546632_.js`

which is version 1.2.6 of jQuery. Note that `.closest` was introduced in version 1.3